# How to return all possible rows in a SQL inline table-valued function

Tags: sql, sql-server

Which parameter do I need to pass in order to get ALL the values possible? For instance, there are 5 movies in my movies table, how do I get them all using this function?

```
create function Count(@movies varchar(20))
returns table
as
    return
        (select count(*) as NumberOfMovies, movies.MovieID
         from movies
         where movies.MovieID = @MovieID
         group by movies.MovieID)


select *
from dbo.Count()
```

Comment: Using this function it will not be possible, unless you do `SELECT * FROM movies WHERE  -1<>dbo.Count()`   (But that would be cheatting.... )

Comment: BTW: your function has a reference to `@MovieID` which is not declared inside the function. I do not think that is correct!   (MSSQL will not like it, MySQL maybe, but not tested any of them)

Comment: Please add a tag specifying the database, and version,  you are using (using [edit])

Comment: What kind of function do I need to use then to achieve what I want? The function needs to be able to accept a parameter @movies and both display all results. Is that possible with some kind of other function?

Comment: Don't create a function called `count()`.  There already is such a function.  Although there isn't a naming conflict, it is just awkward code.

Answer (score 2):

```
create function Count(@movies varchar(20))
returns table
as
return(
   select *
   from movies
   where movies.title like '%'+@movies+'%' or @movies=''
)
```

When doing `SELECT * FROM dbo.Count('')` you will get all movies.

When doing `SELECT * FROM db.COunt('Christmas')` you will get all movies where the title contains 'Christmas'.

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand the where clause though, could you explain it please?

Comment: I've also tested "where movies.title like @movies" and this works just as fine. Why?

Comment: The `'%'` are used as wildcards. So doing `title LIKE 'Christmas'` should only find movies with a title that is exaclty 'Christmas', doing `title LIKE 'Christmas%' will find titles that start with Christmas, and so on. (It is all explained in this [youtube movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZABT_3t4Iew)

Answer (score 1):

```
create function Count(@movies varchar(20))
returns table
as
return(
   select *
   from movies
   where 
     IF (@movies='All')
    movies.MovieID > 0 --for retriving whole data
    ELSE
    movies.title like '%'+@movies+'%'
)
```

if you sent @movies value "All" then you will see whole data, else you will see what do you send.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the function code to get the behavior you want.

I would suggest:

```
create function Count(@movies varchar(20))
returns table
as
    return (
        select count(*) as NumberOfMovies, MovieID
        from movies
        where (MovieID = @MovieID or @MovieID is null)
        group by MovieID
    )
```

This selects the movies that match exactly the given value (as your original code does). If a `null` value is passed as argument, all rows te returned.